# Is there a way to turn off the mouse pad while typing on laptop? (Solved)

Tags: laptop, lenovo

I know KDE has a widget for that, but I don't seem to find it in Elementary OS.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a Touchpad Indicator could help with this as it seemed to be a "go-to fix" for Ubuntu 16.04 which I used in the past.

To do so, open Terminal and paste these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Then launch touchpad-indicator from the Applications Menu which will place an indicator for your touchpad on the top panel. Click on the icon, select Preferences. You can then check 'Disable While Typing'.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to up vote your answer but I can't since I am new here and I don't have 15 up votes or more.  But I do appreciate your kind and fast answer.

Comment: You are more than welcome! And yes, the whole up-vote vs. reputation thing is tough on new users. For me, it's not a recognition thing but a mechanisim that let people know at first glance that an answer has been provided and deemed correct and reliable. No biggie...hope this worked for you!

Comment: I know I am new here.  But I have a question for you.  Once I find the answer satisfactory, should I close the question thread?   and If I have to, how do I do that?  or should I just leave it like this and forget about it.

Comment: I'm kind of new in a sense, too. I've used Stack Exchange in the past but on a very limited basis so I'm still on a learning curve myself. Both of us may want to read through the Help Center (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help) to answer that one! In my quick glance at the Help page you may want to accept my answer but we may garner another comment from a seasoned user based on our discussion as well giving direction. Sorry, not much help as yet.